# Removing single commas but don't remove 3 adjacent commas in a sentence

Tags: java, regex

In the below sentence:

```
String res = [what, ask, about, group, differences, , , or, differences, in, conditions, |? |]
```

I want to remove single commas (,) but don't want to remove three adjacent commas.

I tried with this regex: `res.replaceAll("(,\\s)^[(,\\s){3}]", " ")` but it is not working.

Comment: Could you post result you are expecting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An easy way to do that is by chaining two `replaceAll` invocations, instead of using only one pattern:

```
String input = 
"[what, ask, about, group, differences, , , or, differences, in, conditions, |? |]";

System.out.println(
    input
        // replaces
        //           | comma+space not preceded/followed by other comma
        //           |                 | with space
        .replaceAll("(?<!, ), (?!,)", " ")
        // replaces
        //           | 3 consecutive comma+spaces
        //           |          | with single comma+space
        .replaceAll("(, ){3}", ", ")
);
```

**Output**

```
[what ask about group differences, or differences in conditions |? |]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code featuring replacement within `find` method:

```
String s = "[what, ask, about, group, differences, , , or, differences, in, conditions, |? |]";
StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("((?:\\s*,){3})|,").matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    if (m.group(1) != null) {
        m.appendReplacement(result, ",");
    }
    else {
        m.appendReplacement(result, "");
    }
}
m.appendTail(result);
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/MHRLGN)

Output: `[what ask about group differences, or differences in conditions |? |]`

The regex - `((?:\\s*,){3})|,` - matches 2 alternatives: either 3 commas separated with optional whitespace (that is captured), or just a comma. If we get a capture, we replace with a comma. If the capture is null, we matched a single comma, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use:

```
String res = "[what, ask, about, group, differences, , , or, differences, in, conditions, |? |]";
res.replaceAll("(?<=\\w),(?!\\s,)|(?<!\\w),\\s","");
```

- `(?<=\\w),(?!\\s,)` - commas preceeded by word, and not fallowed by
  other comma,
- `(?<!\\w),\\s` - comma not preceeded by word

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach:

```
.replaceAll("(,\\s){2,}|,", "$1")
```

- `(,\\s){2,}` will try to find two or more `,` and will store one of them in group indexed as `1`
- `,` can match comma which wasn't consumed by previous regex, which means it is single comma

Replacement `$1` uses match from group 1

- if we found `, , ,` we want to replace it with `,` and such text will be placed in group 1
- if we find only `,` then we want to replace it with nothing, and since earlier regex couldn't find its match all its groups (which in our case is group 1) are also empty.